# Why this is equivalent to proper?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

maybe that's an idiot question. Anyway, when I was reading this master thesis http://sma.epfl.ch/~werndli/scripts/mscthesis/elementary_gaga.pdf I could not understand the following equivalence (in page 4): let $X, Y, Z$ be topological spaces, then $\varphi : X \longrightarrow Y$ is a proper mapping (i.e., a continuous mapping such that, for every $Z$, the pull-back along $\pi_Y :Y \times Z \longrightarrow Y$ is closed) iff $\varphi$ is closed and each one of its fibers is quasicompact.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is false for algebraic varieties with Zariski topology.

Comment: @QiL'8 In any direction of the "iff"? This is a master thesis, so maybe I misunderstood what is written. Could you please take a look at page 4 in the link?

Comment: You are working in which context ?

Comment: @QiL'8 The author does not make the context clear. He says that this equivalence exists, however the converse is true if $X$ is Hausdorff and $Y$ locally compact Hausdorff (I didn't understand this part since he assumed an equivalence for arbitrary $X$ and $Y$).

Answer (score 1):

For Hausdorff spaces it's right and you can check this [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_map). But for a moment pay attention that because of part (b) of exercise 7 of section 1 of chapter 1 of the book Algebraic Geometry of Hartshorne, every Noetherian space is quasi-compact so in Noetherian spaces every map has quasi-compact fibers, so in Noetherian spaces this condition is not giving anything, but have you heard every closed morphism between varieties are proper so far?